# Import mobileads without gradle - Aide

Tags: android, gradle, libgdx, admob, aide

I've made a game with Aide and I'm trying to incorporate Admob, but I'm running into trouble.

I'm using Aide to make it, and it's gradle support is only partly there. There is no build.gradle for libgdx projects in Aide, so I can't add the libraries I need that way. You can add the play services to a normal android app in Aide, and I can initialize mobileads in a blank app no problem.

I tried to copy the com.google.android.gms.ads folder into my game libs, it will import com.google.android.gms.ads - but there's only .R and .manifest that it will import. From what I can tell, there should be a mobileads.class file in the folder, but it's not. A blank app can find it, but I can't with a file explorer, or with my libgdx game.

Is there a workaround for this?  I can't be the only person who has ever made a game in Aide and tried to add ads to it... can someone link me to a download of the class files I need? Or a libgdx gradle file for Aide?

If anyone has any ideas, it'd be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can simply add the Ad dependency & it will add the Ad related Classes.

Comment: I managed to make it work by making a standard gradle app, and manually moving the libgdx files... how would I go about adding the ad dependency instead?